# Filter or Eq out certain parts of the spectrum without introducing transient distortion

Tags: filter, distortion, eq, transients

As we all know windowing function or any kind of EQ'ing could destroy transients, introduce ringing artifacts etc...I wounder is there any other way achieving tasks such as filtering certain partials of the sound without distorting its transients? Would filters that work in time domain do that instead of FIR filters?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your best bet would be to use the Spectral Repair features of [Izotope's RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/repair-and-edit.html) package. Unfortunately, if you're filtering any sound you are inherently likely to introduce artifacting of some sort; how much and how noticeable this is will naturally depend on the frequency components of that sound, and what / how much you're filtering out.

RX generally does a pretty tidy job at allowing you to filter out specific parts of the frequency spectrum without 'damaging' the sound too much, so is worth a look if there's some specific audio you're trying to fix.

Comment: Izotope uses windowing functions, before filtering which destroys the transients, eg. it uses hanning window etc...or there would be side lobes that is caused of discontinuities...

Answer (score 0):

Eq's introduce phase rotation effects , maybe you could hack your way with digital linear phase eq..

But after all its a certain sound you are eqing , if there are unwanted artifacts in a transient well the transient will be  damaged.

There are also multiband compressors like c6 which act very much like an eq but with dynamics

Comment: This is a quote from the FabFilter's site "However, linear-phase filters also have some disadvantages. First of all they introduce latency: the entire signal is delayed when passing through the plug-in. Higher processing resolution (for better response in the low frequencies), results in longer latency, but unfortunately this can also introduce 'pre-ring' that can make transients (e.g. a kick drum) lose their edge.

Comment: Yes thats true , there are different stuff happening when cutting other than boosting though , a test will make it more clear . Also i have never experienced what fabfilter states , maybe it has to do with lower performance machines ... still its not the best solution i agree but could help with some issues that's why i thought of it. Its not a very clear question as if phase introduces a problem or some samples to understand what the op states..